# Is there better way to write such loops when I use dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there better way to write such loops when I use dataframe?
a,b are dataframes(4, 1096)

```
c = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((4, 1096))) 
for j in range(0, 4):
    for i in range(0, 1096):
         c[i][j]=abs((a[i][j]-b[i][j]))/(a[i][j]+b[i][j])
```

Comment: What is `a` and `b` here?

Comment: Just a tip (which doesn't affect the answer) but instead of using chained column and row references, it's better to use `DataFrame.iloc` - as well as being arguably more readable, it sets you up better to avoid `SettingWithCopy` errors later down the line. More detail on this [best practice in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) - HTH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform arithmetical operations on pandas dataframes and pandas will try to match automatically the index for you (i.e. summing together columns/rows with the same label and NaN otherwise). If you want more control on the treatment of missing data, you can look at [add](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) and [sub](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) method ([doc1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#missing-data-operations-with-fill-values), [doc2](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/operations-in-pandas)).

I assume in your case `a` and `b` are two identically labelled dataframes.

So you can simply do:

```
c = ((a - b) / (a + b)).abs()
```

As for your comment on different rows of the DataFrame, you can use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to create a DataFrame `b` such that 'b[i, :]' = a[i+1, :] and then repeat the operation above:

```
c = ((a - a.shift(-1)) / (a + a.shift(-1))).abs()
```

You can easily generalize this for different shifts.

One of the best features of pandas is the index alignment, so I would recommend to avoid loops in pandas, as they are very inefficient and somewhat defeat the purpose of having a pandas DataFrame in the first place.

Should you need very specific loop constructions, maybe you will be better off using numpy.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do so :

```
c = pd.DataFrame(abs((a.values-b.values)/(a.values+b.values)))
```

Comment: thank you. and if I want make loop with different rows of one dataframe? for example      `c[i][j]=abs((a[i][j]-a[i+1][j]))/(a[i][j]+1[i+1][j])`

Comment: You can use `a.shift(1)` or `a.shift(1, axis=1)` Please consider to accept the answer if it is what you wanted :)

Comment: @Debra `c = pd.DataFrame(abs((a.values-a.shift(1, axis=1).values)/(a.values+a.shift(1, axis=1).values)))`